# How to access respsone from AngularJS POST request?

Tags: angularjs, post, jwt

I have a service for signing into my web app which contains the following code:

```
angular.
module('core.user').
factory('User', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        var url = 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:3000/api/authenticate'
        return $resource(url, {}, {
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {},
            }
        })
    }
]);
```

This request is not being made in the frequently used $http.post() method to which most answers on this site refer to.

I wish to access the response from this request as it comes with a token (JWT) and I can see that this works in Postman. I can access the response from GET requests using similar services by using `<serviceName>.$promise.then((data) => {// access data here})` but when I use a POST request I cannot use `.then()` nor `.success()`

Below is the way I try to access the POST response:

```
angular.
module('signIn').
component('signIn', {
    templateUrl: 'sign-in/sign-in.template.html',
    controller: ['$resource', 'Company', 'User', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$window',
        function CompanyListController($resource, Company, User, $scope, $rootScope, $window) {

            // Initialize Variables //
                var self = this;
                self.companies = Company.query();
                self.companies.$promise.then(function(data) {
                    var hold = data
                    data = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < hold.length; i ++) {
                        if (hold[i].CompanyID) {
                            data.push(hold[i])
                        }
                    }
                    self.companies = data;
                })
                self.user = new User();
            // Initialize Variables //

            // Sign In Function //
                self.signIn = function() {
                    if (self.user.name && self.user.password && self.companyID){
                        self.user.$save()
                        location.href = "#!/" + self.companyID
                    }
                }
            // Sign In Function //

        }
    ]
});
```

How can I access the token inside the response from my POST request?

Comment: can you confirm if second answer work or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
self.user.$save(function(response){
    //here is the response
}, function(error){
})
```

or like this

```
self.user.$save().$promise.then(function(response){
    //here is the response
}, function(error){
})
```

[angular $resource documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Worth noting that while I accepted this answer, the second option is the very option I specified does not work. The first works perfectly, but the second throws an error about property of 'then' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
self.User.save(self.user).then(function(response){})
```

Should work